Can we show this operation in terms of a matrix vector product: $\mathbf{A} \odot \left(\mathbf{1} \otimes \mathbf{x}^T\right)^T$?
Can we show the below operation in terms of a matrix vector product?
$\mathbf{Y} := \mathbf{A} \odot \left(\mathbf{1} \otimes \mathbf{x}^T\right)^T$,
where

$\mathbf{x}$ is $n \times 1$ vector
$\otimes $ denotes a Kronecker product
$\mathbf{1}$ is all-ones vector of dimension $m \times 1$
$\odot$ denotes a Hadamard product
$\mathbf{A}$ is a matrix of dimension $n \times m$

ADD:
More specifically, my question is can we show $\mathbf{Y} := \mathbf{A} \odot \left(\mathbf{1} \otimes \mathbf{x}^T\right)^T := \mathbf{B} \mathbf{x}$ with some $\mathbf{B}$? In other words, what can be that matrix $\mathbf{B}$?
ADD: See comments from Ben Grossman. It is possible to do vectorization.
--8< --------------
EDIT (based on Kurt G's comments):
Let us take an example of a simple case.
Say,

$\mathbf{x} = \left[x_1, x_2 \right]^T$
$\mathbf{A} = 
   \begin{bmatrix}
   a_{11} & a_{12}\\
   a_{21} & a_{22}
   \end{bmatrix} $

Then, $\mathbf{Y} := \mathbf{A} \odot \left(\mathbf{1} \otimes \mathbf{x}^T\right)^T$, where $\left(\mathbf{1} \otimes \mathbf{x}^T\right)^T$ replicates the vector $\mathbf{x}$ such that the output reads
$ \mathbf{Y} = \begin{bmatrix}
   a_{11} x_1 & a_{12} x_1\\
   a_{21} x_2 & a_{22} x_2
   \end{bmatrix} .$

All these nice little thingies can be written out explicitly. Can you do that? Then we can think about your question.

@KurtG. I have explained with an example. Does this make sense to you?

It does, except that I think $(\mathbf{1} \otimes \mathbf{x}^\top)$ should be
$$
\begin{bmatrix}x_1&x_2\x_1&x_2\end{bmatrix}
$$
and we are transposing that again.

@KurtG. True, I forgot to take the transpose before multiplying with matrix $A$. I have fixed it now.

Given vectors $(x,y)$ and matrix $A$ of compatible dimensions
$$\large\eqalign{
\def\D{\operatorname{Diag}}
A\odot(y\otimes x^T)^T ;=; A\odot(xy^T) ;=; \D(x)\cdot A\cdot\D(y) \
}$$

@greg This is good. Now I realized that it is not possible to show in terms of matrix vector product because the final output is matrix.

Note that $\mathbf 1 \otimes \mathbf x^\top$ is exactly the same as the ordinary matrix product $\mathbf 1\mathbf x^\top$

@learning You could use vectorization to produce the vectorized result as a matrix-vector product. For instance, we can find a matrix $M$ such that
$$
M \mathbf x = \operatorname{vec}[\mathbf{A} \odot \left(\mathbf{1} \otimes \mathbf{x}^T\right)^T].
$$
Is this the kind of thing that you're looking for?

@BenGrossmann Aha, thank you. That could be an alternative, then I can do unvec operation to the product of $\mathbf{M} \mathbf{x}$.

Note that $Y$ can be rewritten as $A \odot (\mathbf x \mathbf 1^T)$
Using the (column-major) vectorization operator, we have
$$
\operatorname{vec}(Y) = \operatorname{vec}[A \odot (\mathbf x \mathbf 1^T)] = \\
\operatorname{diag}(\operatorname{vec}(A)) \operatorname{vec}(\mathbf x \mathbf 1^T) = \\
\operatorname{diag}(\operatorname{vec}(A)) (\mathbf 1 \otimes  \mathbf x) = \\
\operatorname{diag}(\operatorname{vec}(A)) (\mathbf 1 \otimes  I_n)\mathbf x.
$$
That is, we can write $\operatorname{vec}(Y) = M\mathbf x$, where $M = \operatorname{diag}(\operatorname{vec}(A)) (\mathbf 1 \otimes  I_n)$.
In the above, the "diag" operator is as it's defined here.
